# Python wrapper for Instagram API

Tags: python, rest, wrapper, instagram

This code wraps the user endpoint and media endpoint of Instagram API. Any best practices/ styles or glaring bugs you can see? I wrote some unit tests for each class but did not include for readability

Base class:

```
import unirest
from oauth2 import OAuth2API


class Client(OAuth2API):
     host = "http://api.instagram.com"
     base_path = "/v1"
     header_default = {"Accept": "application/json"}
     ACCESS_TOKEN_ONLY = ["access_token"]

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Client, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build_path(self, endpoint):
    return self.host + self.base_path + endpoint

def build_params(self, params):
    return params

def build_oauth_params(self, params):
    if params == self.ACCESS_TOKEN_ONLY:
        return {"access_token": self.access_token}
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError("ouath params {} not implemented".format(params))

def parse_request(self, endpoint, accepted_oauth_params, accepted_params):
    path = self.build_path(endpoint)
    params = self.build_params(accepted_params)
    params.update(self.build_oauth_params(accepted_oauth_params))

    return path, params

def get_request(self, endpoint, accepted_oauth_params, accepted_params):
    path, params = self.parse_request(endpoint, accepted_oauth_params, accepted_params)
    return unirest.get(path, headers=self.header_default, params=params)
```

User endpoint class:

```
from client import Client


class User(Client):
endpoint_base = "/users"

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def self(self):
    oauth_params = self.ACCESS_TOKEN_ONLY
    params = {}
    endpoint = self.endpoint_base + "/self"
    response = self.get_request(endpoint, oauth_params, params)
    return response

def self_recent_media(self, count=None, min_id=None, max_id=None):
    oauth_params = self.ACCESS_TOKEN_ONLY
    params = {}
    if count:
        params.update({"count": count})
    if min_id:
        params.update({"mind_id": min_id})
    if max_id:
        params.update({"max_id": max_id})
    endpoint = self.endpoint_base + "/self/media/recent"
    response = self.get_request(endpoint, oauth_params, params)
    return response

def user_id(self, user_id):
    oauth_params = self.ACCESS_TOKEN_ONLY
    params = {}
    endpoint = self.endpoint_base + "/" + str(user_id)
    response = self.get_request(endpoint, oauth_params, params)
    return response

def user_recent_media(self, user_id, count=None, min_id=None, max_id=None):
    pass

def self_liked(self, count=None, max_like_id=None):
    oauth_params = self.ACCESS_TOKEN_ONLY
    params = {}
    if count:
        params.update({"count": count})
    if max_like_id:
        params.update({"max_like_id": max_like_id})
    endpoint = self.endpoint_base + "/self/media/liked"
    response = self.get_request(endpoint, oauth_params, params)
    return response

def search(self, query, count=None):
    oauth_params = self.ACCESS_TOKEN_ONLY
    params = {"q": query}
    if count:
        params.update({"count": count})
    endpoint = self.endpoint_base + "/search"
    response = self.get_request(endpoint, oauth_params, params)
    return response
```

Media endpoint class

```
from client import Client


class Media(Client):
endpoint_base = "/media"

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Media, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def media_id(self, media_id):
    oauth_params = self.ACCESS_TOKEN_ONLY
    params = {}
    endpoint = self.endpoint_base + "/" + str(media_id)
    response = self.get_request(endpoint, oauth_params, params)
    return response

def media_shortcode(self, shortcode):
    oauth_params = self.ACCESS_TOKEN_ONLY
    params = {}
    endpoint = self.endpoint_base + "/shortcode/" + str(shortcode)
    response = self.get_request(endpoint, oauth_params, params)
    return response

def media_search(self, latitude=None, longitude=None, distance=1000):
    oauth_params = self.ACCESS_TOKEN_ONLY
    params = {}
    if latitude and longitude:
        params.update({"lat": latitude, "lng": longitude})
    if distance != 1000:
        params.update({"distance": distance})
    endpoint = self.endpoint_base + "/search"
    response = self.get_request(endpoint, oauth_params, params)
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    params.update({"count": count})
```

seems overwrought.  What's wrong with just `params["count"] = count` ?

Also, code like:

```
endpoint = self.endpoint_base + "/" + str(media_id)
```

always makes me wonder if I'm getting the number of slashes correct, so instead I do:

```
import posixpath
endpoint = posixpath.join(self.endpoint_base, str(media_id))
```